# magento getCollection() can we put where condition?

Tags: magento

i am working on a magento project and i need to get the value according to country wise like select address where `country ="Nepal"`

can we send the where condition in `getCollection()` function

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('relocator/location')->getCollection();
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 22, accepted):

got the solution 
;P

```
Mage::getModel('relocator/location')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFilter('country','Nepal');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use diffrent condition like below reference from [this.](https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/magento/magento-product-collection-bible)

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

Is Equal To

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1));
```

Greater Than

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt' => 3));
```

Contains – with % wildcards
Is NULL

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => 'DVD%'));
```

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => array(1,2,12)));

Comment: really great advice!